# Vue.js submit text button

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vue.js

I have a noob question.

i have a form with a text field.  If i type something in, and push enter, no result.  If i type something in, and push the button, i get the result i want.  Can someone help me fix this - this is written in vue.js

```
    <div class ="well">
    <form class="form-inline" onsubmit="searchName">
    <h1><label>Enter Search</label></h1>
    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" v-model="search">    
    </form>
    </div>
    <input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" v-on:click="searchName" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add an event in your text field.

```
<input 
type="text" 
name="name" 
class="form-control" 
v-model="search"
v-on:keyup.enter="searchName" 
/>
```

Or add a submit event in your form

```
<form 
class="form-inline" 
v-on:submit.prevent="searchName"
>
```

Comment: both of these solutions worked, just that the second seemed to be a better fit for me - THANK YOU to all that contributed!

Answer (score 1):

put your button inside the `<form>` tag and change the button type to `submit`:

```
<div class ="well">
    <form class="form-inline" @submit.prevent="searchName">
        <h1><label>Enter Search</label></h1>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" v-model="search">   
        <input id="clickMe" type="submit" value="clickme"/> 
    </form>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

instead of `onclick` event in the button, use `@submit.prevent` in the form.